# How to compare 2 sorted numeric lists in python where each corresponding element don't have to be exact match?

Tags: python, numpy

Given 2 list of sorted numbers as below:

```
>>> list1 = list(map(int, '7 22 34 49 56 62 76 82 89 161 174'.split()))
>>> list2 = list(map(int, '7 14 49 57 66 76 135 142 161'.split()))
```

numpy.in1d would yield true values for 7, 49, 76 and 161.

But I would like to accept a certain tolerance says up to 3 and yield true values for 7, 49, **57**, 76 and 161 (because 56 in list1 and 57 in list2 is only difference by 1)

I have written the following code to produce the result desired where FifoList() is an implementation of fifo stack:

```
    class FifoList:
        def __init__(self):
            self.data = []

        def append(self, data):
            self.data.append(data)

        def pop(self):
            return self.data.pop(0)

    def match_approximate(a, b, approx=3):
        c = []
        bEnd = False
        bfifo = FifoList()
        for i in b:
            bfifo.append(i)
        y = 0
        for x in a:
            if bEnd:
                continue
            while True:
                if y == 0 or x - y > approx:
                    try:
                        y = bfifo.pop()
                    except KeyError:
                        bEnd = True
                        break
                if abs(x - y) <= approx:
                    c.append(y)
                    break
                if y > x:
                    break
        return c
```

Just wondering if there is another better way to implement this?

Comment: what is desired output?

Comment: What if instead of using lists of numbers you used lists of objects? You could define a class then with a number as the single instance variable, and implement a custom __eq__(self): dunder method that returns true if abs(self.number - other.number) <= 3. You could then automatically use any built in functions that call "=="

Comment: list1 = [7, 22, 34, 49, 56, 62, 76, 82, 89, 149, 161, 182]
        list2 = [7, 14, 49, 57, 66, 76, 135, 142, 161]
        print match_approximate(list1, list2, 3)

Result: [7, 49, 56, 76, 161]

Comment: You could also have a look at the original implementation, it is actually pretty simple (/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/ma/extra.py) look up what's happening in the "if invert ..." control sequence. I believe you can get what you want simply modifying those two lines into inequalities.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you are using a queue here. It doesn't seem like the right data structure for the problem. Furthermore, Python has a built-in queue data structure (`collections.deque`, and just use `popleft()` instead of `pop(0)`).

A simpler way (imo) is to just maintain a "pointer" (or index) to each array, starting at the beginning. If the elements are within `approx` of each other, add them, and increment both pointers. If `a`'s element is less than `b`'s element, increment `a`s pointer.  Else, increment `b`s pointer. Keep going until both pointers are exhausted (i.e. pointing to the end of the list). This runs in O(N), linear time. Here's an implementation of said algorithm:

```
def match_approximate(a, b, approx=3):
    a_ind, b_ind = 0, 0
    result = []
    while a_ind < len(a) and b_ind < len(b):
        if abs(a[a_ind] - b[b_ind]) <= approx:
            result.append(b[b_ind])
        if a[a_ind] == b[b_ind]:
            b_ind += 1
            a_ind += 1
        elif a[a_ind] < b[b_ind]: a_ind += 1
        else: b_ind += 1

    def match_last_element(a, a_ind, last_elt_of_b, result):
        while a_ind != len(a):
            if abs(a[a_ind] - last_elt_of_b) <= approx:
                result.append(a[a_ind])
                a_ind += 1
            else:
                break

    if a_ind != len(a): match_last_element(a, a_ind, b[-1], result)
    else: match_last_element(b, b_ind, a[-1], result)

    return result
```

Running

```
a = [7, 22, 34, 49, 56, 62, 76, 82, 89, 161, 163, 174]
b = [5, 6, 7, 14, 49, 57, 66, 76, 135, 142, 161]
print(match_approximate(a, b, 3))
```

will output `[5, 6, 7, 49, 57, 76, 161, 163]` (which is what I *assume* is expected, but see below about some edge cases that aren't clear). If you run this case on your current impl, you will get an `IndexError`.

It's not entirely clear what to do in some edge cases:

1. When you have an approximate match, which element do you add to the result? This impl just pulls in `b`s element (like the example).
2. How should duplicates be handled? In this impl, if both lists contain a dup, it will be added twice. If only one list contains duplicates, the elements will only be added once. A more complicated example with dups is to understand if we have `[4,5]` and `[4,5]` as input, should our output be `[4,5]` or `[4,4,5,5]` (since `4` and `5` are both within `approx` of each other, `4` also matches to `5`).
3. Is the `approx` bound inclusive or exclusive (i.e. `<= approx` or `< approx`)?

Feel free to adjust the above impl to handle whatever you deem necessary to do in these cases.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its an interesting way to implement without using a FIFO stack. Answers to your question:

1. My actual requirement is to return 2 lists :-P but I have put in the simpler version here for easier understanding

2. This scenario won't happen as my input lists will be at least 5 numbers apart, which is greater than the approx value passed in.

The reason I am using the FIFO queue for second list is to avoid having 2 nested for loops to avoid O(N^2) runtime.

Comment: Have verified using timeit that your code is definitely more efficient and noticeably faster than my original code.

Comment: For my use case, the match_last_element() routine is not required as all remaining items will be discarded. That will further help improve speed of the code.
On top of that, your code makes it much easier to implement a new "invert" requirement where the items in the 2 lists are too close to each other. 
I am attaching my final solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Picking approximate match from X:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([7,22,34,49,56,62,76,82,89,161,174])  #len:11
Y = np.array([7,14,49,57,66,76,135,142,161])       #len:9

dist = np.abs(Y[:, np.newaxis] - X)
#print(dist)
for i in range(len(Y)):
    for j in dist[i]:
        if -3<=j<=3: #approximation of 3
            idx = dist[i].tolist().index(j)
            print(X[idx])
```

**Output:**

```
7
49
56
76
161
```

Picking approximate match from Y:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([7,22,34,49,56,62,76,82,89,161,174])  #len:11
Y = np.array([7,14,49,57,66,76,135,142,161])       #len:9

dist = np.abs(X[:, np.newaxis] - Y)
#print(dist)
for i in range(len(Y)+1):
    for j in dist[i]:
        if -3<=j<=3:
            #print(j)
            idx = dist[i].tolist().index(j)
            print(Y[idx])
```

**Output:**

```
7
49
57
76
161
```

Comment: Solution is definitely succinct and compact in terms of code, but I fear it has O(N^2) runtime. For each element in `X`, you're calculating the difference for each element in `Y`.

Comment: Yes time complexity wise it is not a good approach. I will try to come up with some better algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MattMessersmith, I have implemented my final solution which caters for 2 requirements:

1. Filters items in 2 lists which are too close to each other
2. Matching items in 2 lists which are close to each other

   ```
   list1 = [7, 22, 34, 49, 56, 62, 76, 82, 89, 149, 161, 182]
   list2 = [7, 14, 49, 57, 66, 76, 135, 142, 161]
   >>> result = match_approximate(list1, list2, 3)
   >>> print result[0]
   >>> print result[1]
   [7, 49, 56, 76, 161]
   [7, 49, 57, 76, 161]
   >>> result = match_approximate(list1, list2, 1, True)
   >>> print result[0]
   >>> print result[1]
   [22, 34, 62, 82, 89, 149, 182]
   [14, 66, 135, 142]
   ```

Here is the code:

```
    def match_approximate(a, b, approx, invert=False):
        a_ind, b_ind = 0, 0
        resulta, resultb = [], []
        while a_ind < len(a) and b_ind < len(b):
            aItem, bItem = a[a_ind], b[b_ind]
            if abs(aItem - bItem) <= approx:
                if not invert:
                    resulta.append(aItem)
                    resultb.append(bItem)
                a_ind += 1
                b_ind += 1
                continue
            if aItem < bItem:
                if invert:
                    resulta.append(aItem)
                a_ind += 1
            else:
                if invert:
                    resultb.append(bItem)
                b_ind += 1

        if invert:
            while a_ind != len(a):
                resulta.append(a[a_ind])
                a_ind += 1
            while b_ind != len(b):
                resulta.append(b[b_ind])
                b_ind += 1

        return [resulta, resultb]
```